# MySQL returning results from one table based on id data in another table

Tags: php, mysql

I tried to make this inside this question, but i am too young on #stackoverflow to post comments.
[MySQL returning results from one table based on data in another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760564/mysql-returning-results-from-one-table-based-on-data-in-another-table)

I cannot get this to work. My intentions are slightly different. 
I have two tables (and more in the future) that I intend to work together. I want to keep my db size down, so instead of using full words to reference `time_code_department`, I added a column to reference the "department_id". now I want to grab all the "time_codes" from table where the "time_code_depart" id matches the variable entered.
So if user selects "Solar" department and `time_code_department` table has "9" as the "solar" "department_id", then i want to return all the entries in "time_codes" that have the "department_id" "9" on the `time_codes` table. Which in this example would be lines with `id` 40 and 75.

Table Structure:

```
 ----------------------------------------------
|                 time_codes  (table)          |
|                                              |
| id | department_id | code_number | code_name |
 ----------------------------------------------
| 40 | 9             | 35          | Safety    |
| 52 | 10            | 725         | Inventory |
| 75 | 9             | 18          | Cabinets  |
 ----------------------------------------------


 -----------------------------------
|      time_code_depart (table)     |
|                                   |
| department_id | name    | manager |
 ----------------------------------- 
| 9             | Solar   | John    |
| 10            | Finance | Mary    |
| 11            | Design  | Sue     |
 -----------------------------------
```

I've tried to query:

```
SELECT 'department_id' 
FROM `time_codes` 
INNER JOIN `time_code_depart` 
ON 'time_codes.department_id' = 'time_code_depart.department_id' 
WHERE 'name' LIKE 'Solar'
```

and

```
SELECT 'time_codes.id', 'time_codes.code_number', 'time_codes.code_name' 
FROM `time_codes` 
ON 'time_codes.department_id' = 'time_code_depart.department_id' 
WHERE 'time_code_depart.name' 
LIKE 'Solar'
```

Both of these I formed based on several readings on the subject, and i have used several variation of sentax. I cannot get it to return the entries for the lines with `id` 40 and 75.
Can you help me identify where I am going wrong?

Comment: You are using single quotes when you don't need any quotes at all.  I consider this a simple typographical error and vote to close such questions.

Comment: please don't close this. I have to have quotes or my phpAdmin sends error in syntax. `` for tables and '' for everything else. I don't know why, but it's what works.
I have also tried it without any quotes at all.

Comment: This is the response when i remove all the quotes:
Error
SQL query: Documentation


SELECT department_id
FROM time_codes 
INNER JOIN time_code_depart 
ON time_codes.department_id = time_code_depart.department_id 
WHERE name LIKE Solar
 LIMIT 0, 25 
MySQL said: Documentation

#1052 - Column 'department_id' in field list is ambiguous

Comment: That has nothing to do with removing the quotes. That's because there's a `department_id` column in both tables, and it doesn't know which one you want when you write `select department_id`.

Comment: If I leave the quotes this is the response:
 MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). (Query took 0.0013 sec)

Comment: You should put the table name before column name where joining query. something like: `SELECT 'time_codes'.'department_id'` bla bla

Comment: If I add time_codes.department_id
query being:SELECT 'time_codes.department_id' 
FROM `time_codes` 
INNER JOIN `time_code_depart` 
ON 'time_codes.department_id' = 'time_code_depart.department_id' 
WHERE 'name' LIKE 'Solar'
i get the same result Zero returned.

Comment: Did you try @Barmar 's answer? and what did you get?

Comment: Barmar's answer got me going in the right direction. Problem solved. Thanks to everyone.

Answer (score 2):

You have several problems with quoting.

First, to quote table or column names in MySQL, you use backticks; single quotes are used for making strings.

Second, when you have a table.column, you must quote them each separately.

Note that it normally isn't necessary to quote table and column names at all. They only need to be quoted if they're the same as reserved words, or contain punctuation characters.

```
SELECT `time_codes`.`department_id`
FROM `time_codes`
INNER JOIN `time_code_depart`
ON `time_codes`.`department_id` = `time_codes_depart`.`department_id`
WHERE `name` LIKE 'Solar'
```

And when you have long table names like this, I recommend making use of table aliases to make expressions more readable:

```
SELECT tc.department_id
FROM time_codes AS tc
INNER JOIN time_code_depart AS tcd
ON tc.department_id = tcd.department_id
WHERE name LIKE 'Solar'
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion with the shorter names, however I am very Young with programming and need more sentence structure to "get what i'm reading. When i try your top code i get an error like this,
http://screencast.com/t/fjXQ5LYIFh
Oh wait that was just a misspelled table name. That being fixed i get results, but only the time_codes.department_id column. 
Thank you. 
To add more info Would i add to the begining of the query say: 
SELECT `time_codes`.`department_id`, `time_codes`.`code_number`, `time_codes`.`code_name` 
FROM `time_codes`

Comment: Yes. This is all basic SQL syntax. Any tutorlal should explain it. Do you have a textbook?

Comment: Oh beautiful! That works, and Also I can go back to Using SELECT * FROM to get the full result.
So my error was in using different quotes, only use backticks for structure and single quotes for data variables. Also Join table to column with periods outside the backticks. Thank you.

Comment: no i don't I've only learned from reading web and trial and error. Textbooks are far to technical for me. I wish they were written in common english. any suggestions?

Comment: Try to get out of the habit of using `SELECT *`. Just request the specific columns that you're actually using, don't waste bandwidth transmitting columns you're not going to use in the application.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any suggestions. Google for SQL tutorials.

Comment: Good advice on the SELECT *, I will rewrite my sql statements on this project. Thanks again for all the help.